# java + mongodb runCommand on mongo server

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to execute below command on mongodb server from java code to add capture field.

```
db.users.find({}).forEach(function (user) {
   db.users.update({_id:user._id},{"$set":{"old_doc": user}});
});
```

I have seen runCommand function and use eval, but eval was deprecated on version 3.0. Do we have any way to execute that script?

Note: Because I have a lot of users, so, I don't want query users and  forEach update on java side.

Comment: That's not how you do it. Don't try and `eval` JavaScript from Java, use the "native" Java driver interface instead.

Comment: If I use java driver, I have to query users and for-each on java side, set old_doc then save, it'll take more resource and time, how's your ideas?

Comment: You really should not use `eval` for this, since it's a pretty dangerous thing to do. You can use "bulk" operations to relieve the network overhead, and even run the code on an instance that is "closer" on the network to the server. But I would avoid running an uncontrolled JavaScript loop on the server. If you can live with output to another collection then `.aggregate()` with `$out` would be a better choice.

Comment: Generally though the only time you "should" run `eval` operations is as a "one off" when you really don't have another option. As a "one off" these can be done in the shell. The minute you think you need to put this into your application codebase, you're doing something wrong.